# Edit video h.264 metadata without encode

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, video-encoding, h.264

How can I edit these video (h264) parameters (on pic) without encode?
VUI parameters "video_signal_type_present_flag" and "colour_description_present_flag".
As far as I understand, ffmpeg does not know how to do this:

[image: pic parametres]

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#h264_005fmetadata

Ideas?

Comment: Linux ? Or Windows ?

Comment: I use Windows, but I can try Linux if needed.

Comment: Try: `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0:video_format=0:colour_primaries=0:transfer_characteristics=0:matrix_coefficients=0 output.mp4`. Do you really want to set all the parameters to zero? What tool are you using for showing the VUI NAL Unit?

Comment: @Rotem I use [H264 Stream Analysis](https://sourceforge.net/projects/h264streamanalysis/) on SourceForge. Also, `ffmpeg -i file.h264 -c copy -bsf:v trace_headers -f null -` You command work, but "video_signal_type_present_flag" and "colour_description_present_flag" not edit.

Comment: I don't know the limitations of FFmpeg... When I create H264 file without VUI: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=5 -pix_fmt yuv420p input.264` then execute: `ffmpeg -y -i input.264 -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0:video_format=0:colour_primaries=0:transfer_characteristics=0:matrix_coefficients=0 output.264`, then `colour_description_present_flag = 1`. (I am using FFmpeg 5.1.2 in Windows).

Comment: You can also check if setting the value to non-zero changes the result. Example: `ffmpeg -y -i input.264 -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=1:video_format=0:colour_primaries=1:transfer_characteristics=1:matrix_coefficients=1 output.264`

Comment: I see [h.264 specification](https://i.imgur.com/hXey6PK.png). Any change in the parameters leads to the creation of flags = 1.
Color information cannot be deleted (only unspecified flag).
I think these parameters will always be now = 1 (0 - false, 1 - true).

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg is not known for being a metadata video editor, although
this is possible.

I quote the most-upvoted answer on the post
[How to change metadata with ffmpeg/avconv without creating a new file?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479066/165358)

> You can do this with FFmpeg like so:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.avi -metadata key=value -codec copy output.avi
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $ du -h test.mov 
>  27M  test.mov
> $ ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_format out.mov | grep title    # nothing found
> $ ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i test.mov -codec copy -metadata title="My title" out.mov
> $ du -h out.mov
>  27M  out.mov
> $ ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_format out.mov | grep title
> TAG:title=My title
> ```
>
> See the [documentation for
> `-metadata`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) and on
> [stream copying](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) for more
> information.
>
> Note also that not all formats allow setting arbitrary metadata, for,
> e.g., Quicktime doing `-metadata title="my title"` does what you'd
> expect, but `-metadata foo=bux` does nothing.

I note that there exist specialized products for editing
video metadata that do not need to re-encode the video and have
a good user interface.

Software recommendations are off-subject on our site, but you may start
with the article
[Best Free Video Metadata Editor software for Windows 11/10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/video-metadata-editor-software-for-windows-10).